# VBA Rows Property Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to unhide a range of rows.  This is to be done within a loop, so I'm using variables; here's the code:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Workbooks("Discrepancies1").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 8) = "USRFLG02=T" Then
a = Workbooks("Discrepancies1").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 46).Value
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c, a)

Workbooks("Discrepancies1").Worksheets(1).Rows("i: i + b - 1").Hidden = False

End If
Next
End If
```

However, running this gives me a type mismatch error on the last line of code.  I've checked all the variables, and they are what they should be.  It seems like VBA doesn't like the colon (denoting range) in conjunction with variables.  I can run this without variables, or without the range, but I can't have both.  Suggestions?

Comment: `Workbooks("Discrepancies1").Worksheets(1).Rows(i & ":" & i + b - 1).Hidden = False` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With Workbooks("Discrepancies1").Worksheets(1) 
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If .Cells(i, 8) = "USRFLG02=T" Then
            a = .Cells(i, 46).Value
            b = Application.CountIf(c, a)

            .Rows(i & ":" & i + b - 1).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End With
```